# RTP Client Application on Android Mobile Device

Tags: android, rtp

Hey folks,i am developing a RTP client on an Android device which can play streaming videos from a server. 
I am confused regarding how should i start about?
i am thinking of developing a web app, using HTML,CSS and Javascript, which can later be wrapped in Android.is this approach correct? does javascript support real time media player? 
please guide me, i am a fresher and completely clueless..:(

Comment: on the RTP server side, how did you generate the video stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should play your video with MediaPlayer. Of course you can prepare dedicated website that lists available streams and wrap it up into WebView. Having this stream list in WebView you can write interface that will bind javascript on your webpage with proper interface in your Android code. Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) section of Android Dev Guide:

And [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) is a list of supported media formats

I successfully played rtsp stream on Android 2.2 but I'm not sure if it's supported on previous versions.

To sum up.

1. Prepare website with javascript code and streams list
2. Create layout with webview with javascript enabled for example:

   ```java
   Webview wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
   wv.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ```
3. Add class that will be invoked by javascript like in the Dev Guide above:

   ```java
   wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");`
   ```
4. Play stream with MediaPlayer

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do people keep confusing RTP with RTSP?  They are completely different.  The question here was about RTP, not RTSP.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may setup a streaming media server(live555, darwin stream server) to publish media file in rtsp protocol, and use VideoView on android to play it

Answer (score 0):

If you create normal android app then MediaPlayer class will handle everything for you. Just feed it with rtp stream url, that is it.