# How to send RTP on Android?

Tags: android, rtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RTP Client Application on Android Mobile Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672314/rtp-client-application-on-android-mobile-device)

Are there any robust codes available?

Comment: The other thread is about RTP reception, not sending.  I suggest re-submitting this question, but make sure you make it clear it's not a duplicate - and add more info about what you're looking for and why.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've already got some codes that I　ｗａｎｔ．

Comment: What did you end up doing? A bit interested myself.

Comment: Just search for jlibrtp on Sourceforge.net